# gethostbyaddr() returns NULL but errno result in SUCCESS

Tags: c, sockets

Code follows:

```
struct sockaddr_in ipv4addr;
ipv4addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
struct hostent *he;
he = gethostbyaddr(&ipv4addr, sizeof(ipv4addr), AF_INET);
if(he)
    printf("Host name: %s\n", he->h_name);
else
    printf("Error AHAHA:%s\n", strerror(errno));
```

But it clearly says that

> Return Value
>
> The gethostbyname() and gethostbyaddr() functions return the hostent
>   structure or a NULL pointer if an error occurs. On error, the h_errno
>   variable holds an error number. When non-NULL, the return value may
>   point at static data, see the notes below.

This piece of code result in printing **Error AHAHA:SUCCESS**, and this also means that it run into else, which indicates **he** is **NULL** which shouldn't be.

UPDATE:

```
memset(&ipv4addr,0,sizeof(ipv4addr));
ipv4addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
```

adding these I somehow got the hostname of

```
ANantes-651-1-49-net.w2-0.abo.wanadoo.fr(2.0.0.0)???
```

Comment: And... what are you actually seeing?  Is there a question?

Comment: It says right there in the documentation, `h_errno` holds the error number.  Yet, in your code you're checking `errno`.  Voting off-topic because error is caused by a simple typo.

Comment: Ah, I see, SUCCESS here is the strerror output.   Yeah.  ^ that.

Comment: @Mr.Llama Yeah, what's wrong about checking the errno? This piece of code result in printing **SUCCESS**, and this also means that it run into else, which indicates **he** is **NULL** which shouldn't be.

Comment: What is wrong is that it isn't mentioned in the documentation you quoted. Have another look at it, and at the comments above.

Comment: @RafaelJ h_errno is not the same thing as errno. (also note that strerror() will not translate h_errno)

Comment: I'm not concurring on closure, because the confusion between `h_errno` and `errno` is a semantic misunderstanding, not a typo.  It's completely plausible that others would make the same mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still don't know why I'm getting other host names, but this worked for me

```
char ipv4addr[sizeof(struct in_addr)];
inet_pton(AF_INET, "127.0.0.1", ipv4addr);  
struct hostent *he;
he = gethostbyaddr(&ipv4addr, sizeof(ipv4addr), AF_INET);
if(he)
    printf("Host name: %s\n", he->h_name);
else
    printf("Error AHAHA:%s\n", hstrerror(h_errno));
```

And yes,I changed **strerror(errno)** to **hstrerror(h_errno)**

Answer (score 4):

As others have stated in comments, the `gethostby...()` functions assign the error code to [`h_errno`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/h_errno) rather than to [`errno`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html).  They are not the same thing!  You can also use [`gethostbyaddr_r()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/gethostbyaddr) to get the error code.  But either way, use [`hstrerror()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/hstrerror) instead of [`strerror()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strerror) to report the error message.

You are also not populating the `sockaddr_in.sin_family` field. That is why the code works with using `inet_pton()`. Even though `gethostbyaddr()` takes a family as an input parameter, you still have to pass it a correctly populated `sockaddr_in` so it can validate that you really are passing in an IPv4 address and not another address type, like IPv6.

Try this:

```
struct sockaddr_in ipv4addr;
memset(&ipv4addr, 0, sizeof(ipv4addr));
ipv4addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
ipv4addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
struct hostent *he = gethostbyaddr(&ipv4addr, sizeof(ipv4addr), AF_INET);
if(he)
    printf("Host name: %s\n", he->h_name);
else
    printf("Error AHAHA:%s\n", hstrerror(h_errno));
```