# ERROR on gethostbyaddr: Success

Tags: c, sockets, network-programming, udp

I am building a multiclient UDP server in c,but when i tried to connect to my server from a system, i get this error **ERROR on gethostbyaddr: Success**
Please find the below server code.I have tried the solutions from similar questions([gethostbyaddr() returns NULL but errno result in SUCCESS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30059146/gethostbyaddr-returns-null-but-errno-result-in-success)) but i couldn't get it working.Any help will be greatly appreciated

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

#define BUFSIZE 1024

/*
* error - wrapper for perror
*/
 void error(char *msg) {
  perror(msg);
  exit(1);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  int sockfd; /* socket */
  int portno; /* port to listen on */
  int clientlen; /* byte size of client's address */
  struct sockaddr_in serveraddr; /* server's addr */
  struct sockaddr_in clientaddr; /* client addr */
  struct hostent *hostp; /* client host info */
  char buf[BUFSIZE]; /* message buf */
  char *hostaddrp; /* dotted decimal host addr string */
  int optval; /* flag value for setsockopt */
  int n; /* message byte size */
  FILE *fp; /* file variable */
  char str[10];
  int i = 0;
  char userlist[10];
  int array_size;
  char line[256];
  int cred,flag;

  /*
  * check command line arguments
  */
  if (argc != 2) {
     fprintf(stderr, "usage: %s <port>\n", argv[0]);
     exit(1);
  }
  portno = atoi(argv[1]);

  /*
  * socket: create the parent socket
  */
  sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
  if (sockfd < 0)
    error("ERROR opening socket");

  /* setsockopt: Handy debugging trick that lets
  * us rerun the server immediately after we kill it;
  * otherwise we have to wait about 20 secs.
  * Eliminates "ERROR on binding: Address already in use" error.
  */
  optval = 1;
  setsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR,
        (const void *)&optval , sizeof(int));

  /*
  * build the server's Internet address
  */
  bzero((char *) &serveraddr, sizeof(serveraddr));
  memset(&serveraddr,0,sizeof(serveraddr));
  serveraddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  serveraddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
  serveraddr.sin_port = htons((unsigned short)portno);

  /*
  * bind: associate the parent socket with a port
  */
  if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serveraddr,
     sizeof(serveraddr)) < 0)
     error("ERROR on binding");

  /*
  * main loop: wait for a datagram, then echo it
  */
  clientlen = sizeof(clientaddr);
  while (1) {

   /*
   * recvfrom: receive a UDP datagram from a client
   */
   bzero(buf, BUFSIZE);
   n = recvfrom(sockfd, buf, BUFSIZE, 0,
     (struct sockaddr *) &clientaddr, &clientlen);
   if (n < 0)
      error("ERROR in recvfrom");

   /*
 * gethostbyaddr: determine who sent the datagram
 */
hostp = gethostbyaddr((const char *)&clientaddr.sin_addr.s_addr,
          sizeof(clientaddr.sin_addr.s_addr), AF_INET);
if (hostp == NULL)
  error("ERROR on gethostbyaddr");
hostaddrp = inet_ntoa(clientaddr.sin_addr);
if (hostaddrp == NULL)
  error("ERROR on inet_ntoa\n");
printf("server received datagram from %s (%s)\n",
   hostp->h_name, hostaddrp);
printf("server received %d/%d bytes: %s\n", strlen(buf), n, buf);

fp = fopen("users.txt", "r");
while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp)) {
  //printf("%s\n",line);
  cred = strncmp(buf,line,strlen(line)-1);
  //printf("%d",strlen(line)-1);
  if(cred == 0){
    printf("Authenticated....");
    flag = 1;
    break;
  }
  else{
    printf("Invalid username/password");
  }
}
 fclose(fp);
```

Answer (score 1):

`gethostbyaddr()` expects a pointer to a `struct in_addr` as 1st parameter, which would be `&clientaddr.sin_addr` for the code you show.

Form the relevant (Linux) documentation (`man gethostbyaddr`):

> [...] The host address argument is a pointer to a struct of a type depending on the address type, for example a struct in_addr * (probably obtained via a call to **inet_addr**(3)) for address type **AF_INET**.

---

`gethostbyaddr()` sets the error code in `h_errno` not in `errno`.

Form the relevant (Linux) documentation (`man gethostbyaddr`):

> **RETURN VALUE**
>
> [...[ The **gethostbyname()** and **gethostbyaddr()** functions return the hostent structure or a null pointer if an error occurs.  On error, the h_errno variable holds an error number.

The possible error code are given by the man-page as well:

> **ERRORS**
>
> The variable h_errno can have the following values:
>
> - HOST_NOT_FOUND
>
>   The specified host is unknown.
> - NO_ADDRESS or NO_DATA
>
>   The requested name is valid but does not have an IP address.
> - NO_RECOVERY
>
>   A nonrecoverable name server error occurred.
> - TRY_AGAIN
>
>   A temporary error occurred on an authoritative name server.  Try again later.

Comment: Thank you for the heads up, i tried to get the actual error and the error is **ERROR on gethostbyaddr:Unknown host**, but i tried to ping from each system(both local and remote) using their ip and there is no packet loss, i dont know whats wrong with my code, any idea on what might be the issue here?

Comment: @Natto: Please also see the 1st part of my updated answer.

Comment: I have changed the first parameter and tried, but still i am getting the same error

Comment: @Natto: So it probably *is* unknown, will say the IP address in `clientaddr.sin_addr` does not resolve to a FQDN using DNS or your local `/etc/hosts` file. Try using `inet_ntoa()` to get the text representation of the IP address from `clientaddr.sin_addr`, print it and run a `nslookup` or `dig` for it from the command line to verify this.

Comment: i tried what you have said by including these lines in my code
**hostaddrp = inet_ntoa(clientaddr.sin_addr);
      printf("readable form :%s",hostaddrp);**

But i get zsh: segmentation fault (core dumped) error when i try to access hostaddrp

Comment: @Natto: Make sure you only execute this code if the previous call to recvfrom did not fail. Also take care to test every relevant system call for errors. If the above printf fails, you probably passed null-pointer.